# Conditional selector based on media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the following selector:

```
#elem1:hover,#elem1.clicked{
      ...lots of css here...
}
```

*When the screen is smaller than 800px, I want the selector only to be `#elem1.clicked`.*

Thus, something like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px){#elem1:hover},#elem1.clicked{
      ...lots of css here...
}
```

Is it possible to do a conditional selector based on a media query?/

(I am using SASS, so SASS answers are acceptable, but changing the HTML isn't)

Comment: Your media-query syntax is wrong or has a typo with the brackets…

Comment: I know that that is not valid.  I'm not asking why it doesn't work, but rather how to conditionally remove a single selector (if such a thing is possible)

Comment: No, that’s _not_ possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either reset the property inside the media query. Or not use those properties that differ in the rule inside combined selector. If you want that `#elem1:hover` should not match under 800px width you need to sy that in a separate rule.

Example:

```
#elem1:hover, #elem1.clicked {
    /* maybe basic styles that always apply */
}


#elem1.clicked {
    /* .clicked styles are always shown */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px){

    #elem1:hover {
        /* styles only above 800px */
    }

}
```

Comment: I may have to end up doing this.  There's no difference between the css in the media query and the css not in the media query, only the selector is different, and therefore, I would be duplicating code.

Answer (score 0):

You can either define the base style for #elem1:hover, then apply overrides for #elem1.clicked like this:

```
#elem1:hover {

}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    #elem1.clicked {

    }
}
```

Or, you could go more specific, and add styles depending on the case:

```
#elem1 {
    /* common style */
}

@media not (min-width: 800px) {
    #elem1:hover {

    }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
    #elem1.clicked {

    }
}
```